# Why is @array ~~ $number different from @array == $number?

Tags: perl, smartmatch

According to *Programming Perl*, using smartmatch with "any" on the left and a number on the right checks numeric equality:

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Left | Right |    Description    | Like (But Evaluated in Boolean Context) |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|  Any |   Num |  Numeric equality |               Any == Num                |
```

Therefore, I expect the following to output `1`:

```
my @arr = ('aaa');
my $num = 1;
say @arr ~~ $num;
```

but it actually outputs the empty string.

I thought `@arr` would be converted to scalar `1` because it has 1 element, so `say @arr ~~ $num` would be equivalent to `say @arr == $num`.

Why is `@arr ~~ $num` different from `@arr == $num`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The smartmatch operator obviously doesn't take lists as operands. As such, it evaluates its operands in scalar context. If that was the end of the story, the following wouldn't work

```
my @a = ('aaa', 'bbb');
my $s = 'aaa';
say $s ~~ @a;
```

because it would be the same as

```
say 'aaa' ~~ 2;
```

But it's clear that it does work. That's because smartmatch automatically creates a reference to its operands that are arrays or hashes, just like `push` does to its first operand. That means

```
say $s ~~ @a;
```

is really

```
say $s ~~ \@a;
```

and (your code)

```
say @a ~~ $n;
```

is the same as

```
say \@a == $n;
```

You need to get the length explicitly. The following will do what you want:

```
say 0+@a ~~ $n;
```

Of course, so would

```
say 0+@a == $n;
```

or even

```
say @a == $n;
```

Comment: Thanks to that answer, I spotted the note `The "Like" column is not always an exact rendition`. So it should not be treated as exactly equal alternative

Answer (score 2):

That's because smartmatch takes a reference first. `@array ~~ $num` would be equivalent to `\@array == $num`, which obviously is very very unlikely to be true.

You might want to use my [Smart::Match](https://metacpan.org/module/Smart%3a%3aMatch) module and do `@array ~~ array_length($num)`, `@array ~~ contains($num)` and other things in a non-surprising way.

Comment: From "Programming Perl": `The smartmatch implicitly dereferences any nonblessed hash or array reference,
so the HASH and ARRAY entries apply in those cases`. So it seems that smartmatching must be done on array, not reference, isn't it?

Comment: @caligula: Then "Programming Perl" is subtly confusing. You can blame me a little for that, I was one of the proofreaders…